# GetIt/Injectable missing injectable decorator on abstract class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) and [Injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable), and I have some trouble with GetIt.

It seems that I'm not registering my `DiscordRepository` class, but I can't registering it with a @injectable decorator since it's an abstract class.
What should I do in this case ?

I initialised my dependency injection like so:

```dart
final getFromDependencyGraph = GetIt.instance;

@injectableInit
Future<void> setupDependencyInjection() async {
  await $initGetIt(getFromDependencyGraph);
}
```

The `flutter pub run build_runner build` give me this output:

```
[WARNING] injectable_generator:injectable_config_builder on lib/misc/dependencies.dart:
Missing dependencies in discordlogin/misc/dependencies.dart

[AuthenticationService] depends on unregistered type [DiscordRepository] from package:discordlogin/data/repository/discord_repository.dart

Did you forget to annotate the above class(s) or their implementation with @injectable?
```

My full code is here: https://github.com/BLKKKBVSIK/DiscordLogin
Build it for web. Then launch the app and click on the FAB at the bottom right of the screen to see the error in the app.

Comment: I have a similar problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Hi ! I still don't but I didn't dig into the problem since I switch project ! If you find a fix, could you send it here tho.
It would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solotion?

Comment: @DuyNguyen I didn't

Answer (score 0):

For me it was problem that after flutter 2.0, the project was a by some plugin automatic changed into null-safety which provides unnecessary fields which is null-safety(?), after I clean this up the warnings disapear

Answer (score 0):

Only non-nullable constructor object arguments will generate, even if the underlying class is marked as @injectable.

The solution is to remove the nullable ? directive and replace with a required keyword like so:

change :

```
class SomeSingleton{
 
final SomeInjectable? injectable;

SomeSingleton({this.injectable])
}
```

to :

```
class SomeSingleton{
 
final SomeInjectable injectable;

SomeSingleton({required this.injectable])
}
```

Now the above snippet's SomeInjectable object cannot be null and therefore the generator will inject it accordingly.